# How to calculate difference between String times

Tags: java, string, int

I have a string of: "9AM-5PM"
I would like to subtract these two numbers and find the difference in hours.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: 1. `String#split()` method 2. `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
int intervalHours(String input) {
    String[] ts = input.split("-");         // {"9AM", "5PM"}
    return toHours(ts[1]) - toHours(ts[0]);

}

int toHours(String t) {
    int h = Integer.parseInt(t.substring(0, t.length() - 2));
    if (t.endsWith("PM"))
        return h == 12 ? 12 : (h + 12);
    else 
        return h == 12 ? 0 : h;
}

// ...

System.out.println(intervalHours("9AM-5PM"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void time()
{
    String t="12AM-5PM";``

    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(t,"-");

    String initialTime=st.nextToken();
    String finalTime=st.nextToken();
    int t1=0;
    int t2=0;

    if(initialTime.contains("AM"))
    {
        t1=Integer.valueOf(initialTime.replace("AM",""));
    }
    else
    {
        t1=Integer.valueOf(initialTime.replace("PM",""))+12;

    }


    if(finalTime.contains("AM"))
    {
        t2=Integer.valueOf(finalTime.replace("AM",""));
    }
    else
    {
        t2=Integer.valueOf(finalTime.replace("PM",""))+12;
    }

    System.out.println(t2-t1);
}
```

Comment: You use only first token `initialTime` and forget that 12PM = 12:00, not 24:00

Comment: oops:) @SashaSalauyou